# Kafka Listeners stop reading from topics after a few hours

Tags: spring-kafka

An app I have been working on has started causing issues in our staging and production environment that are seemingly due to Kafka listeners no longer reading anything from their assigned topics after a few hours from the app starting.

The app is running in a cloud foundry environment and it has 13 @KafkaListener, reading from multiple topics based on their given pattern. The amount of topics is equal (each user on the app creates its own topic for each of the 13 listeners using the pattern). Topics have 3 partitions. Auto-scaling is also used, with a minimum of 2 instances of the app running at the same time. One of the topics is under heavier load than the others, receiving between 1 to 200 messages each second. The processing time for each message is short, as we receive batches and the processing part only proceeds to write the batch to a DB.

The current issue is, as stated, that it works for a while after starting and then suddenly the listeners are no longer picking up messages. With no apparent error or warning in the logs. A temporary endpoint was created where KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry is used to look at the Listener Containers, and all of them seem to be running and have proper partitions assigned. Doing a .stop() and .start() on the containers leads to one additional batch of messages being processed, and then nothing else.

The following are the configs used:

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory(){
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaConfig.getConfiguration());
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(){
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.setConcurrency(3);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(5000);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
}
```

The kafkaConfig sets the following settings:

```
PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG: RoundRobinAssignor
MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG: 60000
MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG: 10
MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG: Integer.MAX_VALUE
ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG: false
METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG: 15000
REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG: 30000
HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG: 15000
SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG: 60000
```

Additionally, each listener is in its own class and has the listen method as follows:

```
@KafkaListener(id="<patternName>-container", topicPattern = "<patternName>.*", groupId = "<patternName>Group")
public void listen(@Payload List<String> payloads,
                   @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topics,
                   Acknowledgement acknowledgement){
    //processPayload...
    acknowledgement.acknowledge();
}
```

The spring-kakfa version is 2.7.4.

Is there an issue with this config that could solve the issue? I have recently tried multiple changes with no success, changing these config settings around, moving the @KafkaListener annotation at class level, restarting the Listener Containers when they stop reading, and even having all the processing on the messages be done asynchronously and acknowledging the messages the moment they are picked up by the listener method. There were no errors or warning logs, and I wasn't able to see anything helpful on debug logging due to the amount of messages sent each second. We also have another app running the same settings in the same environments, but only 3 listeners (different topic patterns), where this issue does not occur. It is under a similar load, as the messages received by those 3 listeners are being output to the topic causing the large load on the app with the problem.

I would very much appreciate any help or pointers to what else I can do, since this issue is blocking us heavily in our production. Let me know if I missed something that could help.

Thank you.

Comment: Most problems like this are due to the listener thread being stuck in user code somplace; take a thread dump when this happens to see what the threads are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, after a thorough analysis of the thread dump I discovered that indeed the issue was due to another recently added service which was parking the threads doing the processing indefinitely. After fixing that, the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Most problems like this are due to the listener thread being stuck in user code somplace; take a thread dump when this happens to see what the threads are doing.